# Laravel: DB where return true when compare to (boolean)false

Tags: laravel

Why when I pass false to `Model::where()` and then trying to get `first()` element it always returns me first element instead of `null`?

Example:

I have Referrer model with `hash_id = 123aSd456fGh`

and I try to get this like below:

```
$requestReferrer = false;

$referrer = Referrer::where('hash_id', $requestReferrer)->first();
dd($referrer); // returns first Referrer model with hash_id = 123aSd456fGh
```

FYI

when I pass null in exchange for false it returns null.

Comment: share table data for `Referrer` ?

Comment: Why are you using false? It seems `null` would be most suitable for this use case? Then you can do `->whereNull('hash_id')` .

Comment: $requestReferrer cames form HTTP request and I don't know what value it has. Anyway. The main question is why it works like that and can I prevent these situations in the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**
SQL Server will automatically change the bit value to the varchar value of true or false.

The following works there:

```
$requestReferrer=false;
$referrer = Referrer::where('hash_id', "$requestReferrer")->first();
```

**Or**

```
$requestReferrer = 'false';
$referrer=Referrer::where('hash_id',$requestReferrer)->first();
```

Comment: It will work but I wonder why it works like that and can I prevent these situations in the feature. Passing null works too, it's not the point

Comment: I have updated my answer. For clarity check the same where condition you have used with different column of datatype  interger/decimal etc